# Failed loading skin error message with Spotify

Tags: xubuntu, synaptic, spotify

I just started having this problem. It started just a min ago. I'm running Xubuntu 12.04 64-bit. I went to Synaptic and marked the client for reinstall. Didn't work. Marked it for uninstallation, uninstalled it, then marked it for reinstallation. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you edit your question and be more verbose? How you did that? Where? Using apt-get or synaptic or Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: As per my post I used Synaptic

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal and type:

sudo spotify

Use ctrl+z to divorce the Spotify session from the terminal. If this worked the problem is that the Spotify client needed files that were put in a folder owned by the root user. For some reason or another it lost permission to get those files. Same thing happened to me.

Comment: By the time I got around to trying this, the problem had resolved itself and hasn't happened since.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me - thanks! I'm also running elementary OS Freya.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

This error is caused by the themes u may have selected with in your system settings (under the "application appearances" tab to be specific). Just restore this entire area to system defaults and your all good.