# Opening Spotify shows "Failed loading skin"

Tags: kubuntu, spotify, kde4

Yep, suddenly when I try to open Spotify it shows me this message:

[image]

Output when executing from terminal:

```
15:32:38.744 I [breakpad.cpp:110                ] Registered Breakpad for product: spotify

15:32:38.745 I [translate.cpp:152               ] Reloading language file
15:32:38.745 W [zipreader.cpp:146               ] [zip] file not found in archive: msgid.pob
15:32:38.745 E [resource_loader.cpp:194         ] Loading of skin file(msgid.pob) failed
15:32:38.745 E [translate.cpp:129               ] Spotify resources and binary are out-of-sync. This should never happen.
15:32:38.768 I [translate.cpp:152               ] Reloading language file
15:32:38.768 W [zipreader.cpp:146               ] [zip] file not found in archive: msgid.pob
15:32:38.768 E [resource_loader.cpp:194         ] Loading of skin file(msgid.pob) failed
15:32:38.768 E [translate.cpp:129               ] Spotify resources and binary are out-of-sync. This should never happen.
15:32:38.768 I [breakpad.cpp:269                ] Searching for crashdumps: ~/.cache/spotify/*.dmp

15:32:38.769 W [zipreader.cpp:146               ] [zip] file not found in archive: skin.xml
15:32:38.769 E [resource_loader.cpp:194         ] Loading of skin file(skin.xml) failed
```

Already tried :

- Reinstall *spotify-client* package
- `rm -rf` this directories:

  - `./.cache/spotify`
  - `./.local/share/spotify`
  - `./.config/spotify`
- `sudo spotify` which opens the actual program but wont let me login into the app showing this output in terminal:

  - `[1208/104615:ERROR:nss_util.cc(96)] Failed to create ~/.pki/nssdb directory.`
- According to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341051/failed-loading-skin-error-message-with-spotify)'s last answer I should do this:

> restore this entire area to system defaults

I don't want to do that and lose all my customization, Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I do it like that

```
rm -rf ~/./.cache/spotify

rm -rf ~/./.local/share/spotify

rm -rf ~/././.config/spotify
```

than `whereis spotify`

than simply remove from those locations:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/spotify /usr/share/spotify
```

and than install spotify like it is described in http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-spotify-in-ubuntu

it works but i have loose all my spotify configurations